# Does SpringBoot have some mechanism to simplify factory injection?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Factory injection in Spring

```
//XML
<bean id="bar" factory-bean="barFactory" factory-method="getInstance"/>
//Java
```

How do you do dependency injection with only interfaces and factory classes and no configuration classes ？

```
//Service
public interface MyService {
    void doSomething();
}

//ServiceFactory
public class MyServiceFactory {
    MyService getInstance() {
        //...
    }
}

//Controller
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;
}
```

Comment: how about adding configuration annotation to MyServiceFactory class ?

Comment: Why not add `@Service` and/or `@Component` to the factory? Then you don't need to use XML config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this without adding the xml coding.

```java
@Configuration
public class MyServiceFactory {

    @Bean
    MyService myService() {
        return new MyService() {
                @Override
                public void doSomething() {
                    
                }
            }
    }
}
```

```java
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    public void execute() {
        myService.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually ask Spring to Autowire it.

Have your factory implement ApplicationContextAware. Then provide the following implementation in your factory:`@Override public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) { this.applicationContext = applicationContext; }`

and then do the following after creating your bean:

```
YourBean bean = new YourBean();
applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(bean);
bean.init(); //If it has an init() method.
```